# React updating state in two input fields from form submission

Tags: forms, reactjs, components, state

I am trying to make a simple contact form using React.  Eventually I will send the data collected from the state to a database, but for right now I am trying to just get it to console log the correct values.

Right now, the email field overrides the name field and when I console log both states, name shows up and email is undefined.  Here is my React Component

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import ContactData from '../data/ContactData.js';


class FormContact extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            textArea: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value,
            email: event.target.email
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.name + ' ' + this.state.email);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <label> Name:
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                </label><br />
                <label> Email:
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                </label><br />
                    <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
           </form>
        )
    }
}

FormContact.PropTypes = {
    subName: PropTypes.string,
    subEmail: PropTypes.string
}

FormContact.defaultProps = {
    subName: 'Sam',
    subEmail: ''
}

class Contact extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>CONTACT PAGE</h1>
                <FormContact />
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Contact;
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understand what you want, you could do it as follows :

- Add an empty object in your state for the form values

  `formValues: {}`
- Add the name attribute to your fields

  `<input name="name" .... />`
  `<input name="email" .... />`
- then depending on that name update your state in handleChange function

  ```
  let formValues = this.state.formValues;
  let name = event.target.name; // Field name
  let value = event.target.value; // Field value

  formValues[name] = value;

  this.setState({formValues})
  ```
- And if the values go one level deeper, you could use 
  `value={this.state.formValues["name"]}` instead of `value={this.state.name}` - *where name is the value of the name attribute of your input field*

Thus, everything together should be as follows :

```
class Test extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            formValues: {}
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let formValues = this.state.formValues;
        let name = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;

        formValues[name] = value;

        this.setState({formValues})
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.formValues);
    }

        render(){
        return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <label> Name:
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value={this.state.formValues["name"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
                </label><br />
                <label> Email:
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.formValues["email"]} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
                </label><br />
                    <input className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" />
           </form>
      )
    }
}

React.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

[Here is fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/139140/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll set this up after work -  looks like what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: FormContact is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. - - Produces this error

Comment: To fix the uncontrolled input issue, you have to initialise the formValues object with empty strings for name and email.

Comment: @boky your fiddle is busted when I click on it.

Comment: @unflores Updated.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to `event.target.email` does not exist on the event element.  The value of a text input from an inline-event handler would be `event.target.value` for both email and name.  The quick solution is to create a separate handler for each input:

```
handleChangeName(event) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  this.setState({ name: event.target.value });  //<-- both use the same reference
}                                               //    to get the contextual value
handleChangeEmail(event) {                      //    from the inputs v
  event.preventDefault();                       //                    |
  this.setState({ email: event.target.value }); //<--------------------
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know two different handlers will work, but I feel like there has to be a way to handle it all at once otherwise bigger form submissions would have a TON of handler functions.  There must be a better way (not using refs, because I heard those were bad)

Comment: I see.  In that case, have you tried passing an extra parameter to bind: which be the string name of the value you want to change?  Then the `handleChange` method could use that value in the setState dynamically.  Another option would be to create a Higher Order Component that wraps an input and effectively makes it a 'dumb' controlled input.